# Tensorflow/Keras appears to change my batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am building an LSTM-based Deep Q-learning Network with Python, Keras, and Tensorflow and have run into the following problem. After I have created the network with a given *batch_input_shape* and try to fit the network to data of that shape, I receive the following error:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (64, 1, 10) for
> input Tensor("lstm_34_input:0", shape=(64, 1, 10), dtype=float32), but
> it was called on an input with incompatible shape (32, 1, 10).

I have created the following toy example to simply demonstrate the code which causes the problem.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# Hyperparameters
action_space = range(0, 10)
input_length = 10
batch_size = 64
timesteps = 1
learning_rate = 0.0001

# Create random input variables
state = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(batch_size, timesteps, input_length))
target = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(batch_size, len(action_space)))

# Build the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, input_length), return_sequences=True, activation="tanh",
               recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False))
model.add(LSTM(10, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(len(action_space), activation="relu"))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate))

# Fit the model
model.fit(state, target, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

This creates the error seen above.

My understanding is that the input layer should expect to receive a batch of shape (64, 1, 10) and we pass it this shape. However, the input layer appears to receive a shape of (32, 1, 10). We can verify that state.shape is (64, 1, 10) as expected so at some stage there is a reshaping of this input, or perhaps the error refers to an input to the hidden or output layer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**
I am using Tensorflow **GPU** version 2.3.0
and Keras version 2.3.1

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior with `'tf 2.1'`

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I have updated the question to include the fact I am using tf 2.3.0 and Keras 2.3.1. I will try to up/downgrade my versions to see if this sheds any light.

Comment: add batch_size=batch_size to model.fit for the easy fix, but really you shouldn't hard code the batch size in your network. For the input shape you can just use input_shape=(time_steps, input_length) (or if you want to use batch_input_shape (None, time_steps, input_length) or even (None, None, input_length))

Comment: Thanks, Simon. I had previously been using the latter however I was investigating using statefulness which I believe requires a batch_size. I will try the former solution shortly and see if it solves the problem - thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to find a way to implement `batch_input_shape` in order to use a stateful LSTM, the answer comes from Simon's comment above:

> add `batch_size=batch_size` to `model.fit`

You can also add it to `model.predict()` for a DQN.